# Is there a way to run PHP 5.3 next to PHP 5.4

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, windows-7, xampp

Is there a way to run PHP 5.3 next PHP 5.4? I'd like it to run simultaneously under apache. I'd like to do that on Windows 7 (using Xampp) and on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to have multiple versions of PHP installed.  With IIS it's fairly easy to swap from one to the other, and it should be possible to do this in Apache as well.  However I don't know how one web-server could support multiple instances simultaneously.

Hopefully these links will be of some help:

[How to setup multiple PHP versions on Apache](http://blog.servergrove.com/2011/08/22/how-to-setup-multiple-php-versions-on-apache/)

[Running Multiple Apache Instances](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RunningMultipleApacheInstances)

Answer (score 2):

Can you check with this link. Here they say about running multiple instance of PHP. Don't know whether it will work on Windows. Can you give a check on this.

[PHP Multiple](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/PHP)

Comment: PHP-FPM isn't going to work on Windows. You can use normal `php-cgi` in its place though.

Answer (score 2):

You can run PHP on Apache using CGI, and switch between versions by changing the CGI executable's path and restarting Apache.